# GridView Menu with icons in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, menu, android-image

i'm developing an app for android and want using GridView build a menu with icons. For this I used already existing solution by http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/draw-menu-in-grid-view/, but the in result the system shows that **mThumbIds** - **cannot be resolved to a variable**,  when i try to declare it as an new local variable, the error is still existing. i'm new in android and maybe making very simple mistake, but i can't solve it by myself. So, any suggestions would be helpful. Here is the code:

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(45, 45));
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    private Context mContext;
    private Integer[] mThumIbs = {
            R.drawable.ic_cards, R.drawable.ic_bank,
            R.drawable.ic_currency, R.drawable.ic_calc,
            R.drawable.ic_banking, R.drawable.ic_call,
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
private Integer[] mThumIbs = {
            R.drawable.ic_cards, R.drawable.ic_bank,
            R.drawable.ic_currency, R.drawable.ic_calc,
            R.drawable.ic_banking, R.drawable.ic_call,
    };
```

Instead of **mThumbIbs**, shouldn't this be **mThumbIds**?

Comment: Che Jami, i guess yes, because in link which i mentioned it's so.

Comment: Che Jami, your question pushed me to the solution :) i've putted everywhere in the code mThumbIbs instead of mThumbIds. Now it's working, thanks